# Real time light hitting baked textures on mobile (Android) Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, lighting

I have an issue with my real time light (torch) when it hits textures in a baked scene it adds no light so dark walls stay dark items on tables stay same illumination etc.. If I turn bake of then the lights work fine (well blocky but working) the docs say the light should be additive am I missing something?

This is the same with legacy diffuse or standard shader. Works fine on pc but i did not know that mobile had such restriction.

Any help or advise massively appreciated.

Andy

Comment: Check your quality settings, this might be an issue. For a quick test remove every quality level except the highest one.

Comment: I have reset the lighting panel to default and rebaked lightmaps and everything seems back to normal.  It may have been a bug but thankfully gone fore.  Thanks for your help was just about to try settings when i rebuilt on more time and it worked!